# SQL group by with descending id order

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using Laravel for a radio website. Every song played is stored as a row in a table called `last_played`. We have a page called Top 20 which basically should display the Top 20 most played songs and when they were last played.

Table

```
+----+--------+-------------+
| id |  song  | time_played |
+----+--------+-------------+
|  1 | song_1 |  1510837544 |
|  2 | song_2 |  1510837545 |
|  3 | song_3 |  1510837546 |
|  4 | song_2 |  1510837547 |
|  5 | song_1 |  1510837548 |
|  6 | song_2 |  1510837549 |
+----+--------+-------------+
```

Expected result like this

```
+--------+-------------+-------+
|  song  | time_played | count |
+--------+-------------+-------+
| song_2 |  1510837549 |     3 |
| song_1 |  1510837548 |     2 |
| song_3 |  1510837546 |     1 |
+--------+-------------+-------+
```

And the query we use is as following:

```
$top20 = DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT *,
  COUNT(*) AS count FROM last_played
   GROUP BY song ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 20'));
```

Everything goes well until we display the songs. They are displayed correctly by the number of times they have been played, but each song returned are the ones with the lowest ID. We want to group everything and get the count of the songs played the most, and return the last id of that song too.

A link to the top20 page is here, and as you can see "Sist spillt / last played" is showing the first time the song where played, not the last.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: `COUNT(*)` return the count of records, pass `id` instead of `COUNT(*)`

Comment: you can use ( orderBy (id,DESC)

Comment: `SELECT * ... GROUP BY ...` is invalid SQL.

Comment: It is not invalid if * includes all the fields you are grouping by... But in this case, it is invalid, indeed.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - maybe simplify to top3 for purposes of question

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expcted .. result ..

Comment: But what do you mean by "the last id of that song" ? Does a song have more than one id?

Comment: I think this is the typical request that ends up in "Oh, nevermind, I found the error someplace else, thank you very much for the loss of time"

Comment: Updated with better example and expected result

Comment: @Amarnasan Right now, the OP is nowhere near the correct answer.

Comment: The data set is not representative.

Comment: Then WHAT THE HELL has the id got to do with the question? It is not even in the desired result? You only care for the timestamp!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    song, COUNT(*) AS count, MAX(time_played) AS timeplayed
FROM
    song
GROUP BY song
ORDER BY timeplayed DESC, count DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

I'm not sure if I get your problem.

But this works with your current example data.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
SELECT song, COUNT(song) AS count, MAX(time_played) FROM last_played GROUP BY song ORDER BY COUNT(song) DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

Comment: That gives me the error i started with.. 
http://powerwave.me/topp20
Song number 2: Sabina Ddumba - Kingdom Come was last played today. And i can see the record in the database too, but the query returns the oldest row where time played = 06.02.2017 - 17:12:37

Comment: I take the column "song" is an index to a song?

Comment: Song is the name of the song. All the songs played are stored in the database. If the songs are played more times, more rows are created.